# SQL: Remove the entire value x from a column if that value x is also in the same row as column y where column y's value is a

Tags: sql

Is there any way to remove rows from column X when Y="a"? Eg. Given:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | a |
| 101 | a |
| 101 | b |
| 200 | c |

The end result would be only row where [200, c] exist.

[101, b] is also removed as 101 is also in a. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your RDBMS but I think this is ANSI standard SQL. To retrieve the rows you want, you can use a simple subquery:

```sql
SELECT X, Y FROM TBL WHERE X NOT IN
(SELECT X FROM tbl WHERE Y = 'a')
```

If you want to actually remove (`DELETE`) rows, you can simply `DELETE` with the same subquery:

```sql
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE X IN
(SELECT X FROM tbl WHERE Y = 'a')
```

Since you did not include the table name, I just made one up (`tbl`).